# Eclipse null analysis: potential null in if block with helper method

Tags: java, eclipse

Background: Eclipse null analysis able to understand potential null with code.

for example.

```java
void foo(@Nonnull Foobar foobar){
   foobar.hashCode();
}

void bar(Foobar foobar){
  if(null != foobar &&  && Math.random()>0.5){
     foo(foobar); // generate no error as it never null
     foobar.hashCode();
  }
  foo(foobar); // generate error as it learnt from the if statement, even without @Nullable
  foobar.hashCode();
}
```

But if I am using a helper method for the if predicate. Eclipse lost its mind.

```java
void bar(Foobar foobar){
  if(somethingMakeItReadable(foobar)){
     foo(foobar); // may have warning here
     foobar.hashCode();
  } 
  foo(foobar);
}

bool somethingMakeItReadable(@Nullable Foobar foobar){
  return foobar!=null && Math.random()>0.5;
}
```

For sure. living without helper method can help. Or having extra null check outside the helper method.
But they hurt code readability. Especially it may take few parameters.

Is there a way to make Eclipse null analysis smart to understand the context ?

Comment: I would assume that the the analysis only works inside of a method as a trade-off between analysis complexity (-> speed) and accuracy. External methods are only considered based on their method signature and the annotations.

Comment: You can use a external tool for that. Sonar is free for Java use and it is able to recognize that kind of NullPointerException, even if you use other method.

Comment: How does the helper method make the code more readable, if you have to know that for a non-null `foobar` the helper method returns `true`? Note that Eclipse can also display a warning in the second case, depending on your project settings (not because of the path analysis not including the helper method, but because of the missing null annotation for the parameter and the resulting problems).